# assign a range of numbers for a MySQL field

Tags: mysql

I want to assign a range of numbers for ID field in the following table which is the primary key using MySQL Query. How can I do it.

Thank you in advance.

Revenue_Account (**ID** range is 500 to 600.Upper Limit 600 and lower limit is 500)

(**ID**--------NAME-------Amount)

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what you're asking. Are you asking how to query for a range of IDs that are between 500 and 600? Are you asking about assigning values between 500 and 600? What is `Revenue_Account`, and what is it's relationship to the `(ID----Name------Amount)`?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you means?

```
SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE ID >= MinValue AND ID <= MaxValue
```

Set the MinValue to your minimal value, in your example is 500. Also for the MaxValue.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL numeric value ranges are based on their column data types. If you define a column to be [INT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/integer-types.html), by default it can take values in the range `-2147483648` and `2147483647`. Explicit range check, i.e. check constraint, is not supported in MySQL. You may require SQL triggers for range checking that fires before INSERT and before UPDATE calls and the input values beyond your required range need to be thrown with an Exception.

Some notes on MySQL supported [Numeric Types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/numeric-types.html).